# no 0-arguments constructor, but none used

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I'm trying to extend a class which doesn't have an 0-arguments constructor and because of that I don't use one in my childclass, but it seems that vs generates one, why and what do I have to change? Thanks:

```
public abstract class BasicQuestPart
{
    public String question { get; set; }
    public BasicQuestPart(String question)
    {
        this.question = question;
    }

}

class MultipleChoice : BasicQuestPart
{
    //In this class I get the 0-arguments error
    public MultipleChoice(String question)
        : base(question)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize an `MultipleChoice` instance?

Comment: every class in c# has a default constructor(0- argument construc),even if you dont write one.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto: That is only true for structs, not for classes.

Comment: Can you show the error you have? I test your class and have no error. And why you are afraid of 0-argument constructor?

Comment: The code you've shown compiles fine for me, with no errors or warnings - can you add more context - what type of project is it?

Comment: What makes you think VS generates a default constructor?

Comment: Where have you seen VS create the default constructor?

Comment: error: Fehler 3 'questionary.BasicQuestPart' enthält keinen Konstruktor, der 0-Argumente akzeptiert.

Comment: = Error 3 'questionary.BasicQuestPart' does not contain a constructor, that take 0 arguments

Comment: they are in 2 different files, does that matter? @Tim: I don't use the class yet

Comment: @Peter Burkert it seems, that you are calling 0-argument constructor somewhere in your code

Comment: the class is never used, yet. and when I doubleclick the error, it jumps to the MultipleChoice Class

Comment: @PeterBurkert this might sound silly and like info from a tech-support but have you tried to clean your project and/or re-opened your solution?

Comment: well that was it, just had to delete the debug folder, sorry for that...

Comment: @Peter Burkert it's also helpful to use menu commands `BUILD`->`Clean solution` and then `BUILD`->`Rebuild solution`

Answer (score 1):

VS does not generate constructors, the C# compiler does.

If you specify a constructor yourself, there will be no implicit "0-argument constructor" anymore.

So in your case, you have a constructor that requires a String and passes it to its base class:

```
public MultipleChoice(String question) : base(question)
```

If the compiler gives you an error along the lines of "there is no constructor with 0 arguments for the MultipleChoice class", then you tried to do this somewhere in your code:

```
new MultipleChoice(); //No argument!
```

But you're not allowed to do that, because you removed the implicit 0 argument constructor when you added one that takes a String!

You can fix this by passing a string:

```
new MultipleChoice("Does this solve your problem?"); //Now with a string argument!
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using *MultipleChoice * in your XAML code?

This message will appear only if you try to instantiate your class using the parameterless constructor. Apart from *new MultipleChoice()* statements, the parameterless constructor can also be used by XAML or dependency injection frameworks.

Each XAML tag corresponds to an object that gets instantiated using the parameterless constructor. Attributes are passed to the corresponding dependency properties of the object.

The following code will try to create a MultipleChoice object using the parameterless constructor:

```
<MultipleChoice question="This is my question"/>
```

Your class won't work this way of course, because you have't declared *question* as a dependency property yet.

Dependency Injection frameworks like MEF also use parameterless constructors unless properly configured.